# Powering up an AC-DC power supply under load

Tags: relay, dc-motor, ac-dc, inrush-current

Is it safe to power up a AC-DC power supply while it is connected to a load?

Specifically what I'm trying to do is replace an AC espresso water pump with a 24V/2A Brushed DC water pump. Additionally a 110VAC/24DC Power supply is connected to the Input of the old pump, and the Input of the new pump. So theoretically, when the espresso machine fires up the AC signal for the old pump, the power supply fires up instead, thus powering the DC pump.

Here is the power supply I'm considering:
https://www.mornsun-power.com/html/pdf/LM150-23B24R2.html

I understand that I also need to consider the wattage of the power supply in case it fries the AC pump Relay.

Comment: Load should not be an issue. Inrush to your power supply might be though. What's the relay rating?

Comment: Your desktop PC has an AC-DC power supply and it has load already connected when you turn it on. So generally it can be done safely. For your case, we don't know the properties of the supply and the load, and also if you replace the old pump with power supply, it will take a huge inrush current when it powers up, so can you know if the original relay driving the old pump can handle the jolt when switching the power supply? The power supply may not like to be turned on/off a lot. So it depends on how often the pump gets turned on/off.

Comment: The motor is driven by a RT314012 which is rated for 16A.